# Problem with button activation with v-slot activator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuetify.js

I'm using v-slot:activator with v-btn in my Vuejs project. it works fine but the button stays hovered as if it was pressed

```
       <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="600px">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn color="#F65C38" dark class="mt-1 mr-2" width="209px" v-on="on" v-bind="attrs"> Example Btn </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="text-h5">{{ formTitle }}</span>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>
            <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid">
              <v-container>
                <v-row>
                 

                  
               
           
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
            </v-form>
          </v-card-text>

          <v-card-actions class="d-flex justify-center">
            <v-btn color="#f66037" plain @click="close" elevation="4" dark width="209" class="mb-6"> No </v-btn>
            <v-btn color="#F65C38" @click="save" dark width="209" class="mb-6"> save </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
```

data:

```
dialog: false
```

watch:

```
  dialog(val) {
      val || this.close();
    },
```

method:

```
    close() {
  this.dialog = false;
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
    this.editedIndex = -1;
  });
```

before click
[image]

after click[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove focus manually using native JS method:

```js
document.activeElement.blur()
```

In your example you can place this row into `$nextTick`:

```js
...
close() {
  this.dialog = false;
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
    this.editedIndex = -1;
    document.activeElement.blur()
  });
},
```

Test this [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/VwrOWgg).